# $http response interceptors headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http

I'm sending a custom header from server in a response. In `$http` response interceptor I want to get this header, but the only header I could get is `Content-type` header. How can I resolve my problem?

Piece of my `$http` interceptor:

```
response: function (response) {
            var AuthToken = response.headers('AuthToken');
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
```

`AuthToken` is undefined.

Comment: You don't need `$q.when(response)`, doesn't make any sense here

Comment: did you check in headers tab in network profile of chrome whether server side is sending the headers or not

Comment: Angular's response header handling seems pretty good to me. It even fixes a `getAllResponseHeaders()` bug in firefox. Try `console.log(response.headers())` to see the whole collection. BTW, is this a JSONP request on another domain?

Comment: It is post request on another domain. Log: `Object {content-type: "text/html;charset=UTF-8"} `

Comment: If it is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) request you should configure the target server to also return `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` to instruct the browser that JavaScript from the other domain is allowed to read certain headers.

Comment: It seems that I did something wrong with CORS requests. Now I make requests on the same domain and everything works OK.

Comment: I did add `AuthToken` to `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

Answer (score 29):

This is a CORS issue.

The response should include `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` listing the specific headers you'd like to use.

e.g.
`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AuthToken, AnotherCustomHeader`

Depending on your server setup, this could be set site wide using an .htaccess file (Apache)

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers AuthToken,AnotherCustomHeader
</IfModule>
```

Or set per request in your server code (php)

```
header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AuthToken, AnotherCustomHeader');
```

Comment: Thank you. So surprising to see it in the net panel but not in angular code. Makes sense now.

Comment: @YaronU. I try. Well...sometimes... :P

Answer (score 0):

@slamborne, Is sounds good.
For .Net

```
 <system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
         <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="AuthToken"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
```